# Supremum of a complicated function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, optimization

I am new here. I have to find supremum of a function:
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$
where
$$
f(x) = \dfrac{\beta \exp(-\beta x) \int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right) \,\mathrm{d}x}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\beta \exp(-\beta x) \,\mathrm{d}x \int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right) \,\mathrm{d}x}
$$
and
$$
g(x)=e^{-x} \;.
$$
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In $f$, the integral on the top and the second integral on the bottom cancel.  The first integral on the bottom is just some constant, so call it $M$. Then

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\beta e^{-\beta x}}{Me^{-x}} = \frac{\beta}{M}e^{(1-\beta)x)}.$$

$M$ is postive, but the final answer depends on whether $\beta$ is negative, between $0$ and $1$ or greater than one.

By the way, this is not a "complex" function, because there are no $i$'s in sight.

Comment: It seems the first  integral in the denominator of f diverges... my guess is the first $dx$ in the denominator of f should not be there.

Comment: @Matt True.  And probably true.  A little context would help here.